# Rough performance estimation for the code Matlab to c++

Tags: performance, mobile

I am planning to port MATLAB algorithm into mobile devices. As part of my proposal i need to give rough estimation of the computation time required for the algorithm on mobile devices. I have figures for the algorithm on MATLAB. It would be great if someone share their experience how should get the rough number for a given mobile platform.

Update:
I am currently targeting to make proposal for the following mobile specification ,Operating System  Android 5.1.1 Lollipop Display  8-inch 1920x1200 LCD Processor  Tegra K1 quad-core at 2.2 GHz 192-core Kepler GPU Storage   16GB MicroSD card expandable

Comment: For anything approaching a remotely useful quantified answer you're going to have to give a lot more detail about both the platforms you are working on, source and target.  And about your program(s) -- memory usage, CPU usage, i/o usage, etc.   Does the mobile device have a CPU with vectorised 64-bit f-p registers ?  And a host of other technical details.  Even with all that you'll get educated guesses at best.

Comment: I am currently targeting make proposal on the following tablet specification  ,Operating System Android 5.1.1 Lollipop
Display 8-inch 1920x1200 LCD
Processor Tegra K1 quad-core at 2.2 GHz 192-core Kepler GPU
Storage 16GB MicroSD card expandable